# Running meteor in my app throws ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: meteor, terminal

I am trying to run an app on my machine. I cloned the app from github and when I run Meteor in the app, it throws this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Boomb\AppData\Local\Temp\mt-1hs6w69.tzxb\os\emgee:libphonenumber.js'

This is where the file is thrown:

C:\Users\Boomb\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:218
      throw error;

I have tried resetting Meteor and installing the `libphonenumber` package.
I am running on windows 10.

Comment: "I cloned the app from github" would you like to share to link to the repository?

Comment: did you create the directory as suggested in Error?

Comment: 'emgee:libphonenumber.js is not a valid name for a js file. and without the 'emgee:' it still doesn't run. So essentially I tried but it didn't do anything

Comment: Try to reinstall METEOR or update METEOR if you are running old one

Comment: I have already tried reinstalling Meteor. I get the same error when I try to update the project, but it also says the project is up to date before the error is thrown.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more information, like the url of the repo you have cloned. In order to get help you need to provide code. If you look at it from our perspective, all that is provided is an error message and little other information. Would you be able to help someone else with just that information?

Asking a question here can be a bit of work to ask a good question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try removing the npde_modules folder and reinstall using `sudo`. If it still doesn't work, you can remove 'emgee:libphonenumber' package from the app and try running it.